# Как рандомно вывести значения из массива в ViewController

Tags: xcode, swift

В ViewController есть 2 поля и кнопка. Смысл такой, что в 1 поле выводится английское слово (рандомно), а во 2 поле выводится перевод этого слова. И кнопка для рандомной генерации слов.

**Я создал 2 массива для английский слов, так и для русских:**

```
var englishWord = ["Apartment", "Actor", "Arm", "Anger", "Ash", "Army", "Action", "Attitude", "Aisle", "After"]    
var russianWord = ["Комната; Квартира", "Актер, Артист", "Рука", "Гнев", "Зола, Пепел; Прах", "Армия", "Поступок, Действие", "Позиция; Отношение к", "Проход", "prep- После, Через; adv- Потом"]
```

**Гетер и сетер для вывода в полях**

```
var english: String {
    get {
      return englishInput.text!
    }
    set{
      let englishvalue = "\(newValue)"
      englishInput.text = "\(newValue)"
    }
  }

  var russia: String {
    get {
      return russianInput.text!
    }
    set{
      let russiavalue = "\(newValue)"
      russianInput.text = "\(newValue)"
    }
  }
```

**Если написать так:**

```
 englishInput.text = String(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(englishWord.count)))
```

Выводится только элементы массива

**А, если написать так:**

```
let engRandom = String(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(englishWord.count)))    
englishInput.text = [engRandom]
```

то выкидывает ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы генерируете число, но не берете элемент из массива по этому индексу, а выводите это число.

Должно быть:

```
let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(englishWord.count)))
englishInput.text = englishWord[index]
russianOutput.text = russianWord[index]
```